# Best practice in android for using thread in UI inorder to load a web page?

Tags: android, multithreading, webview, load, progressdialog

Can any one suggest me the best practice for loading a webview in android? I need to show the progress dialog while the page is loading and need to cancel the dialog if page loading finished. Now I'm using the runnable thread for this, but there is a small delay between thread and page load finish. Is TimerTask or AsyncTask prefferable in this context?
Thanks!!

Comment: did u tryed async task class?

Comment: @MT8 Not yet!! Is it preferrable regarding performance?

Comment: yeah if in case ur internet goes down ur app will crash ...instead u use Async Task Concept works nice and u are able to show progress bar very easily

Comment: @MT8 Thanks for the guidance!! I'll try Async Task :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView is already loading Data asynchronously. You don't need an extra Thread for that. Anyway AsyncTask is in most cases preferable for tasks which only last a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks!! will try AsyncTask:)